# Rails: How to filter search results without loading them into memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, lets call it the `Product` model for this example. I have about 200k records in this database, where half of them are `active` (`active: true`) and half are not. When users are doing a search for products, I only want active ones to be shown. My code looks something like this:

```
def self.search
  products = Products.where(active: true).order("`foo` = 'BAR'")
  products = products.where(other_filters)
  products = products.where(more_filters)
  ..
end
```

Doing so loads the first 100k active ones into memory (doing a `puts products.size` after the first `where` returns `100000`), these are then filtered down about 20 more times with chained `where` clauses and paginated at the end so that only 25 are shown. Is there a more efficient way of filtering these results?

Comment: Are you using some ORM like ActiveRecord? You could just chain the .where's to ensure the database only returns the ones matching all filters.

Comment: In ActiveRecord chaining `.where` creates a single query. You can also use [`.merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) to merge scopes together. Are you really just looking for a less clunky way to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`where` doesn't run a database query instead it returns an instance of [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). And in fact, your example doesn't run a database query at all. It only chains more and more conditions to the relation.

The actual query to the database is run when you actually need the records to return a result. Some examples of methods that trigger loading from the database: `count`, `first`, `each`, `map`, `load` or `inspect`.

That said as longs as you do not output intermediate result (with `puts` for example) you are safe and you do not run necessary queries. Just chain all conditions together.

Btw you might want to simplify your code by removing the `products` variable:

```
def self.search
  Products
    .where(active: true)
    .order("`foo` = 'BAR'")
    .where(other_filters)
    .where(more_filters)
    # ...
end
```

Comment: Just as a quick side note: `to_s` doesn't run a query, but `inspect` does. `puts` does as well because (I assume) it's array-like and so each element gets output to a new line (thus running `each` or equivalent)